# Getting error while passing event.target.value in angular html

Tags: angular

show error in ($event.target.value)

addproduct.component.ts

```
onSelectCateg()
  {
    this.subcategoryservice.getallsubcategory().subscribe(
      response =>{this.listsubcategory = response;}
     );  
  } 
  
  onSelectScateg(id: number)
  {
   this.subcategoryservice.getonesubcategory(id).subscribe(
      Response =>{
        this.subcategory = Response;
        this.title = (10000 + this.subcategory.rang).toString().substring(1);
        this.title = this.subcategory.id_categ+this.subcategory.title+this.title;
        this.f['title'].setValue(this.title);
        }
     );  
  }
```

addproduct.component.html erreur en event.target.value

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="title_categ" id="title_categ" (change)="onSelectCateg($event.target.value)">
    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
      <option *ngFor="let item of listcategory" value="{{item.title}}">{{item.title}}</option>
 </select>
 <label>title SCatégorie </label>
 <select class="form-control" formControlName="title_scateg" id="title_scateg" (change)="onSelectScateg($event.target.value)">
      <option value="0">-Select-</option>
      <option *ngFor="let item of listsubcategory" value="{{item.title}}">{{item.title}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should add more details.

Comment: Note it’s best practice to copy the error into your question, helps seo and finding similar q&a’s, though in this case it’s pretty obvious what the error will be

Answer (score 0):

This will be a type error. It’s better practice to pass event to the function and then narrow the type in your typescript file:

*html*

```
someFunction($event)
```

Or cast via the `$any` function

*html*

```
someFunction($any($event).target.value)
```